# How do I remotely logout of a device where I am logged in with MS Account

Tags: microsoft-account

I had a laptop where I had logged in using my Microsoft Account. However, it needed some repair, as it was not powering on. When I took it to an authorized service center (outside warrenty), the repair value was insane. So I decided to buy a new one, and sell the former (defective) one for a low price.

Is it possible to log out of Microsoft Account of that defective laptop remotely, as  the laptop is not switching on ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  You will want to remove the  device from your Microsoft account.

You can do that from a web browser by navigating to http://account.microsoft.com/devices

For detailed instructions visit this Microsoft Support page: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/remove-a-device-from-your-microsoft-account-dda2c664-9d57-e5db-acf0-67f14d5fdf3c

Have a great day.